# What metrics can be used to evaluate each cluster in clustering

Tags: machine-learning, statistical-significance, clustering, scikit-learn, heteroscedasticity

I am clustering a dataset, where the binary ground truth (positive/negative samples) is known.
I am looking for specific clusters that show high homogeneity/purity. I know that there are many metrics that can be used to evaluate the complete clustering (homogeneity_score, completeness_score ...).
But what metrics could be used or calculated to evaluate each cluster?

For example in this case:

```
cluster   0   1    2   3   4   5  6
target                             
0         4   0  128   0   0  68  0
1        62  23   74  10  12  18  1
```

It is clear, that clusters 1,3, and 4 a homogenous. And cluster 1 would be the one that has the highest significance for me since it contains the most unique labels.
What metrics could be used to compute this property?

I have the feeling a basic statistic test such as the chi-square test of homogeneity or Fischer exact test could be used here, but I need scores for each cluster and I am not sure how to apply the correct test.

Comment: For each of the 7 clusters, you can form 2x2 frequency table: ground truth (1 vs 0) by cluster (this cluster vs not this cluster). Apply any criterion you like which measures an agreement between two partitions.

Comment: (A not bad collection, with formulas, of criteria of agreement to compare clusterings or classifications can be found on my web-page, collection "Compare partitions".)

Comment: Although this is a nice approach which would allow me to compute Fischer's exact test and thereby agreement of cluster with ground truth, it is not the homogeneity I am looking for.

Comment: Then your question is unclear. Add concrete formulas to your question which exemplify what you are looking for.

Comment: OK you are correct, I should have been more clear, I settled for the proportion of positive samples per cluster. However, I am still interested in general metrics to define inner group homogeneity.

Comment: For 2x2 tables, many measures become informationally equivalent. For general case,  n x m tables, popular metrics which are about "homogeneity" and "completeness" are F Clustering Accuracy measure and Homegeneity-Completeness V measure (cay find formulas if you follow my second comment).

Comment: My problem with 2x2 tables is, that they also take into account the # of not this cluster instances; however, I am looking for metrics that only consider the cluster in question.

Comment: If you have only one cluster, say, 0, with counts 4 and 62, and no "other cluster", all you can do is to play with the two figures. Turn them into percents, multiply the two percents or compute the geometric mean. There's not much to invent with just two counts.